# DataGridView Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm running into an error when using DataGridView in VB. I'm working on this in Visual Studio 2015, tied to an AccessDB. The error is `"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."` I have a search button that when clicked, it updates the DataGrid with information from the DB. Now, I want to be able to check a box and have an action performed that will update the date when the RENEW button is click. When I select the checkbox and click on Renew, that's when I get the error. I have tried searching for a solution but I'm not coming up with a good answer. Here is my code (**The lines are marked with **** where error is being thrown in the code**. Everything works find up until this point):

```
Public Class MyAccount

    Dim RowData As Object
    Dim CheckoutPeriod As Long
    Dim NumberOfRows As Integer
    Dim CheckedOutRecord As Integer
    Dim bookinfo As Object
    Dim resourceid As String
    Dim Resourcestatus As String
    Dim DueDate As Date
    Dim checkoutdate As Date
    Dim memberid As String = GlobalVariables.LogInMemberID

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
            dgvMyAccount.Rows.Clear()

            'determine the number of books the current member has checked out.
            NumberOfRows = CheckoutTableAdapter.FillByMemberCheckout(Library_DBDataSet.Checkout, memberid)

            'if the member has at least one book checked out then…
            If NumberOfRows > 0 Then
                    Dim x As Integer = 0

                    'begin a loop that will add information for each of the currently checked out books one at a time, to the DataGridView
                    'you can reorder these columns, remove some of them or add new ones as you wish
                    For x = 0 To NumberOfRows - 1 Step 1
                            bookinfo = CheckOutTableAdapter.GetDataByMemberCheckout(memberid)(x)
                            resourceid = bookinfo.resourceID
                            RowData = ResourceTableAdapter.GetDataByResourceID(resourceid)(0)

                            'calculate the due date for a book based on the check out date and the book’s checkout period.
                            checkoutdate = bookinfo.checkoutdate
                            CheckoutPeriod = RowData.checkoutperiod
                            DueDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, CheckoutPeriod, checkoutdate)

                            'at “due” to the due date so that the member knows when the book is due
                            Resourcestatus = "Due " & DueDate.Date

                            'add information for the checked out resource to the DataGridView
                            Dim dgvRow As New DataGridViewRow
                            Dim dgvCell As DataGridViewCell

                            'add title to the first column of the DataGridView
                            dgvCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
                            dgvCell.Value = RowData.title
                            dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell)

                            'add author’s last name to the 2nd column of the DataGridView
                            dgvCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
                            dgvCell.Value = RowData.authorlast
                            dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell)

                            'add publication date to the 3rd  column of the DataGridView
                            dgvCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
                            dgvCell.Value = RowData.publicationdate
                            dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell)

                            'add series to the 4th column of the DataGridView
                            dgvCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
                            dgvCell.Value = RowData.Series
                            dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell)

                            'add checkout data to the 5th column of the DataGridView
                            dgvCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
                            dgvCell.Value = checkoutdate.Date
                            dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell)

                            'add resourcestatus, created above, to the 6th column of the DataGridView
                            dgvCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
                            dgvCell.Value = Resourcestatus
                            dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell)

                            'add checkout period to the 7th column of the DataGridView
                            dgvCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
                            dgvCell.Value = RowData.CheckOutPeriod
                            dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell)

                            'add checkout period to the 8th column of the DataGridView
                            dgvCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
                            dgvCell.Value = RowData.ResourceID
                            dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell)
                            dgvMyAccount.Rows.Add(dgvRow)
                            'Results is the name of the DataGridView Control added to the Form
                    Next
            ElseIf NumberOfRows = 0 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("You have no items checked out at this time.")
            End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckoutBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            Me.Validate()
            Me.CheckoutBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Library_DBDataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub MyAccount_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Library_DBDataSet.Resource' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            Me.ResourceTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Library_DBDataSet.Resource)

            'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Library_DBDataSet.Checkout' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            Me.CheckoutTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Library_DBDataSet.Checkout)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRenew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRenew.Click
            Dim currentdate As Date = Date.Today.Date
            NumberOfRows = CheckoutTableAdapter.FillByMemberCheckout(Library_DBDataSet.Checkout, memberid)
            If NumberOfRows = 0 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("You have no items checked out at this time.")
            Else
                    If dgvMyAccount.SelectedCells.Count = 0 Then
                            MessageBox.Show("Please select the book you wish to renew")
                    Else
                            'renew book by altering the due date and updating the record selected in ‘the “results” data grid
                            'the numbers in parentheses are the index of the 'data grid column holding the piece of
                            'Information needed.

                            '***********************************************
                            resourceid = dgvMyAccount.SelectedCells(7).Value
                            '***********************************************
                            CheckoutTableAdapter.RenewBookUpdateQuery(currentdate, resourceid)
                            CheckoutPeriod = dgvMyAccount.SelectedCells(6).Value
                            DueDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, CheckoutPeriod, currentdate)
                            Resourcestatus = "Due " & DueDate.Date
                            dgvMyAccount.SelectedCells(5).Value = Resourcestatus
                            dgvMyAccount.SelectedCells(4).Value = currentdate
                            MessageBox.Show("you have successfully renewed your book.", " Book Renewal Successful", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                    End If
            End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: SelectedCells? Are you sure you have 8 selected cells at that point. Do you mean to use SelectedRows(0).Cells(7)?

Comment: I could have one selected cell or I could have more than one. Once I pull the records form the AccessDB, I want the user to be able to select multiple records and when the click renew, it should update the date in the DB. I have 9 columns in the DGV and the ninth column is the checkbox column.

Comment: I found out what was generating the error. My 9th column was a checkbox that I wanted to use. When a user checked the button, the due date in that row would be updated when the user clicked RENEW. However, this isn't working. What is work is when I select an entire row, it will update the record successfully. This will work but I'm wondering if there's a way of using the checkbox instead of having the user know to select the row.